# Agora video streaming with ARCore

Tags: android, arcore, agora.io

I'm using Agora video broadcasting API and trying to broadcast the ARCore scene.
Found in Agora documentation rtcEngine().setVideoSource method to get a consumer of frames.
I'm able to get ARCore frames and trying to pass it to the consumer like this:

```
private volatile IVideoFrameConsumer mConsumer;

...

private class ExternalVideoInputThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Frame frame = mVideoGridContainer.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
            try {
                Image im = frame.acquireCameraImage();
                ByteBuffer buffer = im.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();

                mConsumer.consumeByteBufferFrame(
                        buffer,
                        MediaIO.PixelFormat.TEXTURE_OES.intValue(),
                        width,
                        height,
                        0,
                        frame.getAndroidCameraTimestamp());
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 / DEFAULT_SHARE_FRAME_RATE);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work and the audience side is not seeing the frames. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use this ARCore Github example: https://github.com/ysc1995/ARCoreAgora. In AgoraARStreamerAcitivity, you can find the logic to set custom video source. Thanks!

Comment: That works! Thanks